# Do we owe gratefulness to God in Hinduism?

Tags: gods, karma, dharma

If yes, what should we be grateful for? and aren't all good and bad things result of our own karma? Then why should we be grateful? and if we need to be grateful can we be angry too if things don't go our way?

Comment: The Lord is out father, our mother. Is it not the duty of a mother or father to care for their children?